# How to check the age of a tag?

Tags: linux, git, bash, ubuntu

I try to get the age of a specific tag without make checkout, let me explain, for example in this webpage : http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/refs/tags
I try to get the the age of the tag xorg-server-1.18.0 which is 6 days ago, I have this command :

```
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%ar"
```

but these command only works with the current tag, and obviously im not in the tag xorg-server-1.18.0, someone knows a command for check the age of a tag without make check before ?

Comment: Doesn’t `git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%ar" xorg-server-1.18.0` work?

Comment: yes , this exactly what im looking for, veryt thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass any object to `git log` too, but `git show` is probably more appropriate for this.

```
git show --pretty=format:%ar xorg-server-1.18.0
```